# How to create a F# based Visual Studio Add-In?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Even with F# installed, Visual Studio 2008 (and probably 2010) only provides Add-In project templates for C#, VB.NET and C++.

So, how to create a F# based Add-In?

I have tried to create a F# class library project with a new class implementing IDTExtensibility2, setting the correct references (EnvDTE, Extensibility, ...), copying a few project attributes from the C# Add-In (mainly the command line for debugging), and creating the .AddIn manifest file by hand, but no success. When VS is launched, my Add-In is not listed in the available ones.

What are the missing steps? Some kind of COM registration somewhere?

Comment: [VsVim](http://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim) is an excellent VS add-in written in F#, if you want to see how someone else did it.

Comment: In fact, it is using a C# project as the root of the plugin, but with the rest of assemblies in F#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what went wrong: I simply forgot to put the .AddIn file in the AddIn directory (the C# wizard is doing this automatically).

So, to create a F# based Add-In for Visual Studio:

- Create a new F# class library project
- Add a few reference assemblies to the project (mainly EnvDTE, EnvDTE80, EnvDTE90, Extensibility)
- Create a new class implementing IDTExtensibility2
- Copy the debugging properties of a C# based Add-In project into your F# project
- Copy the .AddIn manifest file, and modify it according to your F# project
  *.. and don't forget to copy that new file in the AddIn directory for the user session
- enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this exact scenario, but the general strategy I've had the best luck with is: start with the C# template, rename the .csproj to .fsproj and change the `<Import>`s for F# and replace the `<Compile>` of C# code with F# code, and go from there.

The templates often have various important logic in them for build/deployment, so start with a working template for C# and tweak it for F#.